# What is the effect of not closing a file opened with open or fopen

Tags: c

To make the question more clear:

[case 1]

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()  {
    FILE* file = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
    return 0;
}
```

[case 2]

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    int fd = open("myfile.txt", O_RDONLY);
    return 0;
}
```

What happens when the file is not properly closed on both examples? Are the buffers flushed into the files? I am assuming the files will at least be closed automatically...  is that right?

Comment: "files will be closed" is an extremely vague statement that's impossible to answer with "yes" or "no". What's a "file"? What's an "open file"?

Comment: The file is `myfile.txt`. An open file is a file I am reading with `fopen` or `open`. I am confused about how can that possibly not sound objectively clear, but I would gladly accept a suggestion of better terms to describe what I want :)

Comment: @KerrekSB if nothing's written, assume POSIX :)

Comment: valgrind will report that as "possibly lost"

Comment: @pap42: is an eventfd or a network socket an "open file"? What about `stdin`? The subject is far more complex and the terminology overloaded to such an extent that simple statements like "open file" are never self-descriptive.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I would say yes, they are open files. The way I see (in my ignorance, I should say), `open` doesn't care about the nature of the "file" you are opening, so the buffer should always be flushed to whatever type of thing you are dealing with, no?

Comment: Well, in any case I wanted to point out that there are many different notions of "file" that have very different contexts and semantics: Files on a file system, file handles in the OS (e.g. file descriptors in Posix), and file streams in the C library. None of them need to map to any particular other one, and each has a separate notion of being open or flushed. Some things are taken care of by the OS, others are the responsibility of a library or of yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fopen` is a C library function. It is unspecified how it is implemented. [*Correction:*] If you return from `main`, all open file streams are closed for you (e.g. C11 7.21.3/5), but this need not happen if the program exits in other ways (e.g. via signal, such as via `abort`).

Your underlying OS implementation will of course clean up everything properly when a process terminates, but that's only in as far as the global state of your system is concerned (e.g. all virtual memory associated to your process will be released, and all file descriptors closed, etc.). If the C library implements its own write buffer, say, then there's no reason that that would automagically get flushed in every situation (though normal exit by returning from `main` is fine).

That also addresses your case 2: If you use OS features directly, like the Posix `open` call, then you are indeed assured that those file descriptors will be closed when your process exits.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. All open files are closed before program termination.

> (C99, 7.19.3p5) "If the main function returns to its original  caller, or if the exit function is called, all open files are closed (hence all output streams are flushed) before program termination."

Comment: @pap42 the C Standard C99 draft http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf