# Lua: Is File Closing Mandatory?

Tags: file, lua, io, fopen, fclose

Let's say I want to store `passwd` content in a variable, just like this:

```lua
local passwd = io.open('/etc/passwd', 'r'):read('a')
```

Is it ok that I didn't close the file after reading? Should I rewrite it like this:

```lua
local f = io.open('/etc/passwd', 'r')
local passwd = f:read('a')
f:close()
```

I know that first piece of code works, but I do not — if it can cause some hidden problems.

*I'm using `Lua 5.3`*

Comment: Number of simultaneously opened files is limited by OS.  So, having a lot of not-closed files, next invocation on `io.open` might fail.  BTW, Lua automatically closes files when file objects are garbage collected, but this behavior is not very helpful as GC is lazy by its nature.

Comment: Lua's `io.open` is implemented in terms of the standard C `fopen` function. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12235826/9593596), the identical reasoning applies here I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Lua `FILE*` is a resource handle similar to an `std::ifstream` or `std::ofstream` in C++. Resource handles are meant to automatically allocate and then deallocate resources--a fundamental concept in object-oriented programming.

Lua `FILE*`s have `close` functions in their metatables, which is what you are calling in your example with `f:close()`. This is to close them explicitly. But, in the OOP-style, they are closed *implicitly* using the `__gc` metamethod. Here is an example I quickly wrote to test this:

```
function myclose(self)
    io.close(self)
    io.stderr:write(string.format("File closed\n"))
    return
end

file = assert(io.open("input.txt", "r"))
debug.getmetatable(file)["__gc"] = myclose
```

In the last line, I change the value of `__gc` to `myclose`; thus, when this `FILE*` object's lifetime ends, `myclose` gets called instead of the default function. This means that "File closed" is printed to `stderr` when the script exits.

So, to get back to your original question, it is unnecessary to explicitly close Lua files.

Comment: How does your answer relate to [the Lua manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-file:close), which says that files should be closed explicitly since garbage collection can take "an unpredictable amount of time to happen"?

Comment: @RolandIllig The link you provided does not say that Lua files *should* be closed, only that the garbage collection of a file handle takes `takes an unpredictable amount of time to happen`. I concede that explicitly closing files is a good idea, especially if many files are being opened; however, I maintain that it is not always necessary. Also, see my comment on the answer by user253751 about triggering a garbage collection cycle.

Answer (score 6):

Lua will close files when the file object is garbage-collected - as Personage said in their answer.

However, that might not be *soon*. If you don't close files yourself, then:

- If you keep opening files, you could run into the maximum number of open files before they get closed automatically.
- On some platforms, other processes might not be able to open the file for writing, while you have it open for reading.
- If you open a file for writing, data that you write might not actually be stored in the file until it gets closed.
- Since garbage collection is related to *memory* usage, which has nothing to do with files, the file might not be closed for a long time if you don't allocate much memory.

Comment: Good point regarding Lua's garbage collection system. If any of these become an issue, you may want to explicitly force a garbage collection cycle by calling `collectgarbage("collect")`.